# Looking for a word -- Stiching side of clothes is public

Tags: word-choice

Yesterday, I saw someone who by mistake had worn the T-Shirt incorrectly. The stitching side was public.

As you can imagine I am still struggling to put my thoughts across. Please help me find the word or sentences I could have used to informed him about that.

Comment: The shirt was (or was worn) *inside out*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would say:

> He is wearing his shirt **inside out**.

Inside out is most common for clothing, but you can use it for anything related to indicate the surface that is normally facing inwards is now facing outwards.  For example, the recent Pixar animated film ["Inside Out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Out_(2015_film)) in which a young girl's inner thoughts and emotions were the main characters.

It also has a [few other definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inside%20out) which you should know, to avoid confusion.